# Split circle in tikz unevenly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circles

How can split  circle (tikz shape circle) in two parts. However, I would like the split to be uneven i.e. the top part occupy lets say 30% of the area and lower part the rest 70%.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to fill a circle segment so the circle segment takes up a specified area of the circle, you'll need to iteratively solve the area equation for the [central angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) of the segment.

Here's a way to do this using [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\radius{1}

\tikzset{ % Declare the function and its derivative
    declare function={f(\a) = 1/(2*pi)*(2*\a - sin(2*deg(\a)));},
    declare function={fprime(\a) = 1/(2*pi)*(2 - cos(2*deg(\a)));}
}

\newcommand\newton[4]{ % arguments: function, derivative, start value, precision
\edef\a{#3}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\fold{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\deriv{#2}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{\a-(\fold)/(\deriv)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\residual{abs(#1)}%
\ifdim \residual pt > #4 pt%
    \newton{#1}{#2}{\a}{#4}%
\fi%
\edef\pgfmathresult{\a}%
}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\fraction{0.7}
\newton{f(\a)-\fraction}{fprime(\a)}{1}{0.00001}
\pgfmathsetmacro\angle{deg(\pgfmathresult)}

\fill [cyan!50]
    (-\angle-90:\radius)
    arc [
        start angle=-\angle-90,
        end angle=-90+\angle,
        radius=\radius
        ]
    -- (-\angle-90:\radius);
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=\radius] node {\pgfmathprintnumber{\fraction}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `path picture` with two rectangles be faster for this?

Comment: @percusse: How would you specify what fraction of the circle is filled?

Comment: I used the taylor expansion on `x-sin(x)` to solve a polynomial. But on a second thought I think that would also be a rough approx.

Comment: Jake, this is simply brilliant. Thanks so much. I wanted to fill the lower part with text. Usually, with regular circle split I would have used keyword lowerpart followed by text. I am quite happy with the current solution.

Answer (score 4):

Without even a mock-up of what you want it is difficult to understand what it is that you need, or where you are having trouble doing this, but one possibility would be to use polar coordinates, as explained in section 13.2.1 ("Canvas, XYZ and Polar Coordinate Systems") of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

You can then specify coordinates with an angle and the distance instead of `x` and `y` magnitudes. This is one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
  \draw (36:1) -- (0,0) -- (144:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is not what you want, you'll have to be more specific.