# hrule into tikz circle node

Tags: tikz-pgf, rules, tikz-node, tikz-shape

I am struggling with inner node layout with Tikz. Basically, I want to add a line under the first text line inside a node, splitting it unevenly. Here is a try:

[image: Two tikz nodes, one with a stupidly huge white space into its first part, and another not split]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm,
        style1/.style={ellipse split, draw, align=center},
        style2/.style={ellipse, draw, , align=center},
    ]

        \node[style1] (1) {NODE1 \nodepart{lower} long name \\ foo \\ bar \\ baz};

        \node[style2] (2) [right of=1] {NODE2 \\ long name \\ foo \\ bar \\ baz};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `split` option seems to be able to split the ellipsis in half, leaving an enormous white space above the first line of text (see NODE1). I wish to render something like NODE2, but with a line separating the first line from the others. Here is an example of the desired output :

[image: The desired output]

I tried to add `\hrule` command just after the "`NODE2`" text, but it does not seem to be possible. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

By the way, please note that I saw [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138673/split-circle-in-tikz-unevenly) and its accepted answer, but I believe it does not address my issue.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the desired output? Maybe draw it by hand if you cannot provide a digital version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something of that sort?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm,
        style1/.style={ellipse split, draw, align=center},
        style2/.style={ellipse, draw, , align=center},
        lower elli/.style={align=center},
        fit elli/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt,
        path picture={\draw ([xshift=-1cm]#1.south west)-- 
        ([xshift=1cm]#1.south east);}}
    ]

        \node[style1] (1) {NODE1 \nodepart{lower} long name \\ foo \\ bar \\ baz};

        \node[style2] (2) [right=1cm of 1] {NODE2 \\ long name \\ foo \\ bar \\ baz};

        \node (3a) [right=3.5cm of 2.north,anchor=north] {NODE3};
        \node[lower elli] (3b)[below=0pt of 3a] {long name \\ foo \\ bar \\ baz};
        \node[fit elli=3a,fit=(3a) (3b)]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems a bit hard to position and align with other nodes if that is required by the OP (e.g. `[right of=1]` will not have them vertically aligned anymore)

Comment: @sheß Vertical alignment is not really an issue to me. But it might be for someone, indeed.

Comment: @sheß If you want to position relative to each other, there is no problem. You could then position the upper parts relative to each other.

Comment: True. Though that would still change behavior compared to a normal node, especially when nodes vary in size. But this seems not to be an issue for the OP

Answer (score 5):

You could just draw a longer [h]rule and clip the node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\def\clap#1{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#1\hss}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm,
    styleshess/.style={ellipse, draw, align=center,clip},
]
    \node[styleshess] (2) {NODE2\\\clap{\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}}\\ long name \\ foo \\ bar \\ baz};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play around with that line as with any other `\rule` to modify positioning or width. The `\clap` makes sure that the (imaginary) length of that line does not blow up the size of the node. The `clip` in the style definition makes sure that only the part of the line that falls within the node is actually drawn.

Comment: This seems to have a larger gap than in the screen shot of the OP. (Personally I do not like these kinds of comments, but you started that.)

Comment: That solution is closest to what I tried, but I prefer the breakdown into two nodes suggested by @marmot : I feel I can control more easily the style of each subpart of the ellipsis. The code is more elegant to me, however.

Comment: That space is easily adjustable with the usual techniques as pointed out in my post. You could write `NODE2\\[-0.5\baselineskip]\clap{...` or something of that sort to reduce that space. I didn't intend to be nasty or start a game of tit-for-tat with my comment on your post, I just thought easy positioning might be a factor for people drawing nodes in tikz. Nevermind.

Comment: You could just add a tabular instead. (These kinds of shapes generally have issues when relative positioning unless you position relative to their centers.)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you mean add a tabular inside the node? What do you mean by "[t]hese kinds of shapes"?